# Did Lord Hanuman have any siblings?

Tags: ramayana, hanuman

Hanuman is an important character in the epic Ramayana. He is called as the son of the wind God as he was born by the grace of the wind-God. His mother was Anjani and father was Kesari.

Hanuman himself describes it in Sundara Kanda [chapter 35](http://valmikiramayan.net/utf8/sundara/sarga35/sundara_35_frame.htm):

> कौरजो नाम वैदेहि गिरीणाम् उत्तमो गिरिः |
>   ततो गच्छति गो कर्णम् पर्वतम् केसरी हरिः || 5-35-80
>
> "O Seetha! There is a mountain called Malyavan, which is the best among mountains. From there, a monkeys called Kesari went to another mountain called Gokarna."
>
> तस्य अहम् हरिणः क्षेत्रे जातो वातेन मैथिलि |
>   हनूमान् इति विख्यातो लोके स्वेन एव कर्मणा || 5-35-82
>
> O Seetha! I am born in the womb of the wife of that Kesari the monkey, by the grace of the wind-god. By my activity alone, I am renowned as Hanuma in this world.

The other details are not described in this chapter.

But in the [Yuddhakanda chapter 28](http://valmikiramayan.net/utf8/yuddha/sarga28/yuddha_28_frame.htm), when the messengers of Ravana, Shuka and Sambada describe the strength of army of Vanaras, Shuka explains about Hanuman as follows:

> **ज्येष्ठः केसरिणः पुत्रो** वात आत्मज इति श्रुतः |
>   हनूमान् इति विख्यातो लन्घितो येन सागरः || ६-२८-१०
>
> **jyeṣṭhaḥ kesariṇaḥ putro** vāta ātmaja iti śrutaḥ |
>   hanūmān iti vikhyāto langhito yena sāgaraḥ || 6-28-10
>
> This monkey, by whom the ocean was traversed, **is the eldest son of Kesari.** He is known as the son of wind-god and famously called as Hanuman.

This verse implies that he had siblings. Generally, people tend to think that Bhima is the brother of Hanuman. Yes, he is but he was not the son of Kesari as mentioned in the Ramayana.

- Did Hanuman have any siblings?
- What is their story?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. Hanuman had siblings.  Matiman, Srutiman, Ketuman and Drtiman were his siblings. Hanuman was eldest son.

**Chapter 7 Upodgatapaada of Brahmanda Purana**  says

> 223-227. The fierce (Sugriva) stayed with his brother for many years
>   like a Deva (a god) .  Kesari married the daughter of Kuåjarä named
>   Aijanä. That lady of great purity and good fortune went to a park
>   named Pumsavana. Väyu (the wind-god ) made advances to the lady who
>   was proudof her youth. Hanumän was born of her by her union with Väyu
>   the (source Of) life into the entire  universe. The sons of Kesari
>   were well known here as well as in the heaven.  '**The eldest among them
>   all was Hanumån. Matimän is  remembered as the son after him. Others
>   were Srutimän Ketumän and the intelligent Dhrtimän.** All the brothers
>   of  Hanuman were well established along with suitable and befitting 
>   wives. The sons were thus established by their father. They  were
>   blessed with sons and grandsons.
>
> 228-230. Hanumän was a Brahmacärin (observer of the  vow of celibacy).
>   He was not joined in wedlock with any woman.  He was like another
>   Garuda in speed and extensive expedition.

Comment: This solves the question of hanuman's marriage too. Were they all the sons  of Vayu or of Kesari?